# When refreshing the page,cause session variables to be cleared

Tags: php, session

Why in reloading page `$_SESSION` variables re-sets again?!

```
  if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && ((time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) > 1800)) 
            {
                // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
                session_unset();     
                session_destroy();   
            }
            $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
            $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
            } else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 1800) {
                // session started more than 30 minutes ago
                session_regenerate_id(true);    // change session ID for the current session and invalidate old session ID
                $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  // update creation time
            }
```

Is my code wrong?
In my php.ini

```
session.cache_expire = 180    
session.use_cookies = 0    
session.use_only_cookies = 0   
session.auto_start = 0    
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440   
session.cache_expire = 180
```

---

I have `session_start()` at top of page
`var_dump($_SESSION)` in page results deferent `$_SESSION` values !!

```
array (size=2)  
  'LAST_ACTIVITY' => int 1472457503  
  'CREATED' => int 1472457503
```

Refreshing again !

```
array (size=2)
  'LAST_ACTIVITY' => int 1472459001
  'CREATED' => int 1472459001
```

The `LAST_ACTIVITY` is normal when changes
BUT why `'CREATED'` is changed!!??

Comment: The variables are probably reset because you start a new session every time the page is loaded (so also in the case of a reload)

Comment: _$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();_ is set each call

Comment: if(!isset($_SESSION['CREATED']))  {  $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time(); }

Comment: comment this line in else if condition //$_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  // update creation time

Comment: may i know that why need that else if condition ?

Comment: The LAST_ACTIVITY is normal when changes
BUT why 'CREATED' is changed!!??

Comment: i think no need that else if condition there

Comment: it is necessary to know when session is created ..for example if 30 minutes ago session was created i want to re-generate session_id

Comment: yeah need that else if you have to setup your session time out and cookie time out minimum half on hour like this   // server should keep session data for AT LEAST  half on hour 
 ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1800);

 // each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY  half on hour
 session_set_cookie_params(1800);

Comment: I have testes  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1800); and session_set_cookie_params(1800);  BUT still not works and it changes session variables.if you see above i have this in my php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

My problem was `session.use_cookies = 0` i.e session was disabled to use cookies.
because session uses cookies to save SID .

**So** if `cookies` disabled and `session.use_trans_sid` is `0` in php.ini with page reload `session_start()` generates new session.

cookies may disable from server side with `session.use_cookies = 0` or with with user browser settings.

**Then how to use sessions without cookies ?!**

Session will work when cookies is disabled. But first apache check php configuration settings. Like:

```
  --enable-trans-sid
and
   --enable-track-vars
```

if these value are set true the session will passed by POST automatically.

If "--enable-trans-sid" and "--enable-track-vars" values are set to FALSE, we need to pass session id by using the SID constant.

```
< a href="index.php?<?= SID ?>" >Navigate from here< /a >
```

Need to set php.ini

```
ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0);
ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", 1);
```

> **Notice :**  trans sid support is disabled by default in php. Use of trans sid may risk your users *security*. Use this option with
>   ***caution***.User may send URL contains active session ID  to other person via email/irc/etc  URL that contains active session ID may be
>   stored  in publically accessible computer  User may access your site
>   with the same session ID   always using URL stored in browser's
>   history or bookmarks.
>   more detial : [session.use_trans_sid](http://php.net/session.use-trans-sid)